# Is it possible to emulate `git add -A` in GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I've recently discovered **GitPython**, and, given that I'm currently trying to create a Python script which pushes to and pulls from Git repositories automatically, I was really excited to try it out.

When committing to a repository using command line Git, I call **`git add -A`**, pretty much to the exclusion of all other arguments. I know that you can call `git add .` instead, or add/remove files by name; I've just never felt the need to use that functionality. (Is that bad practice on my part?) However, I've been trying to put together a GitPython script today, and, despite combing through [the API reference](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html), I can't find any straightforward way of emulating the `git add -A` command.

This is a snippet from my efforts so far:

```py
repo = Repo(absolute_path)
repo.index.add("-A")
repo.index.commit("Commit message.")
repo.remotes.origin.push()
```

This throws the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-A'`. If, instead, I try to call `repo.index.add()`, I get: `TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'items'`. I understand that `.add()` wants me to specify the files I want to add by name, but the whole point of GitPython, from my point of view, is that it's **automated**! Having to name the files manually defeats the purpose of the module!

**Is it possible to emulate `git add -A` in GitPython? If so, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you linked goes to a version of GitPython that supports [invoking the Git binaries themselves directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.cmd), so you could just have it run `git add -A` for you.

That aside, `git add -A` [means](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.
>
> If no <pathspec> is given when `-A` option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

So `git add -A` is just the same as `git add .` from the top level of the working tree.  If you want the old (pre-2.0) `git add -A` behavior, run `git add .` from a lower level of the working tree; to get the 2.0-or-later `git add -A` behavior, run `git add .` from the top level of the working tree.  But see also `--no-all`:

> This option is primarily to help users who are used to older versions of Git, whose "git add <pathspec>…​" was a synonym for "git add --no-all <pathspec>…​", i.e. ignored removed files.

So, if you want the pre-2.0 behavior, you will also need `--no-all`.

If you intend to do all of these within GitPython without using the `git.cmd.Git` class, I'll also add that in my experience, the various Python implementations of bits of Git vary in their fidelity to fiddly matters like `--no-all` (and/or their mapping to pre-2.0 Git, post-2.0 Git, post-2.23 Git, etc.), so if you intend to *depend* on these behaviors, you should test them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
repo = Repo(absolute_path)
repo.git.add('-A')
repo.git.commit('-m', message)
```